# python 3.5 : quit a if loop (or other loops)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running the program, the user is asked to input a number. If the number is 1, quit the program. If the number is not 1, print the number.

I wonder how to realize this.

I am using python 3.5.

My code is like this. I always get an error: `'break' outside loop`

How can I fix this?

```
x = input('Please input a number: ')
if x == '1':
    print('quit')
    break
else:
    continue
print(x)
```

Comment: where is the loop ? If is just checking the value.. You dont have a loop to break

Comment: Its because you need loops. Find the usage of break and continue in general programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error break outside loop because the keyword break is used to break out of a loop. You are using it outside of a loop so you get the error. To exit the application you should not use break. Instead you should use:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

So now your code should look like this:

```
x = input('Please input a number: ')
if x == '1':
    print('quit')
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print(x)
```

You do not need the continue in the else statement either. You can just simply leave the else statement empty and the program will continue on or you can put `print(x)` inside of the else statement like I did with your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you quit an application. Try `sys.exit(error)` where error is the error number.

`break` allows you to escape loops, like this:

```
while True:
    line = 'test'
    if line = 'test':
        break
print "now I'm not in the loop"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a loop in your code, so you'll need to add a while statement. Set the condition to True to have it always run. You also don't need the else continue statement since that would skip the print(x). X is automatically being cast to an integer, so cast it to a string.

```
while True:    
    x = input('Please input a number: ')
    if str(x) == "1":
        print('quit')
        break
    print(x)
```